# SetInputType returns error code c00d6d60

Tags: c++, winapi, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to use MediaFoundation dolby encoder in my project. I am able to initialize output type but while setting up input tyep it gives me c00d6d60 error code

```
IMFMediaType* pInputMediaType = NULL;
    IMFMediaType *pOutputType = NULL;
    if (!m_pMFT)
    {
        return MF_E_NOT_INITIALIZED;
    }
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    DWORD pcInputStreams = 0;
    DWORD pcOutputStreams = 0;
    CHECK_HR(m_pMFT->GetStreamCount(&pcInputStreams,&pcOutputStreams));

assert(pcInputStreams==1 && pcInputStreams == pcOutputStreams);
hr = m_pMFT->GetStreamIDs(1, &m_dwInputID, 1, &m_dwOutputID);

if (hr == E_NOTIMPL)
{
    // The stream identifiers are zero-based.
    m_dwInputID = 0;
    m_dwOutputID = 0;
    hr = S_OK;
}
else if (FAILED(hr))
{
    goto done;
}

SafeRelease(&m_pOutputType);

CHECK_HR( MFCreateMediaType( &pOutputType ) );
CHECK_HR( pOutputType->SetGUID( MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Audio ) );  
CHECK_HR( pOutputType->SetGUID( MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFAudioFormat_Dolby_AC3 ) );
CHECK_HR( pOutputType->SetUINT32( MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, inSamplePerSec ) );
CHECK_HR( pOutputType->SetUINT32( MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND, inOutputAvgBytesPerSec ) );
CHECK_HR( pOutputType->SetUINT32( MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, inNumChannels ) );


LogMediaType(pOutputType);
hr = m_pMFT->SetOutputType(m_dwOutputID, pOutputType, 0);

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    m_pOutputType = pOutputType;
    m_pOutputType->AddRef();
}

CHECK_HR( MFCreateMediaType( &pInputMediaType ) );
CHECK_HR( pInputMediaType->SetGUID( MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Audio ) );
CHECK_HR( pInputMediaType->SetGUID( MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFAudioFormat_PCM ) );  
CHECK_HR( pInputMediaType->SetUINT32( MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, 16 ) );
CHECK_HR( pInputMediaType->SetUINT32( MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, inSamplePerSec ) );
CHECK_HR( pInputMediaType->SetUINT32( MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, inNumChannels ) );
//CHECK_HR( spMFTypeIn->SetUINT32( MF_MT_AUDIO_PREFER_WAVEFORMATEX, 1 ) );
CHECK_HR( pInputMediaType->SetUINT32( MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT, inNumChannels*2 ) );
CHECK_HR( pInputMediaType->SetUINT32( MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND, inNumChannels*2*inSamplePerSec) );
LogMediaType(pInputMediaType);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    goto done;
}

hr = m_pMFT->SetInputType(m_dwInputID, pInputMediaType, 0);
```

The guide I am using is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. Can some please provide some insight

Answer (score 1):

`0xC00D6D60` [is](http://alax.info/blog/1383) `MF_E_TRANSFORM_TYPE_NOT_SET` "A valid type has not been set for this stream or a stream that it depends on."

MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that this error code is returned when it is too early to set input/output media type and you need to configure transform from the other end.

In case of Dolby Digital Audio Encoder real cause should be the unavailability of the encoder to you:

> Important  The Microsoft implementation of the Dolby Digital technology **is restricted** under terms of the Dolby Digital licensing program to use by Microsoft applications.

If you are using third party transform (you don't show instantiation code), then additional conditions or initialization sequence might apply.

Comment: I also tried by initialising Input before output stream but again the setting of input stream gives me same error code.

Comment: I also tried with GetInputAvailableType and it returns the error code c00d36b3

Comment: Did you read my notes on `1` your code to instantiate the MFT, `2` restrictions applicable to Dolby MFTs?

Comment: Yes Roman R. I did read you comment but it didn't solve my problem. The real culprit was CHECK_HR( pOutputType->SetUINT32( MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND, inOutputAvgBytesPerSec ) );  It was causing setting input type to fail. After commenting it my code is working fine. Thanks