# What causes 'A valid type has not been set for this stream or a stream that it dependes on' exception during video playback

Tags: c#, uwp

We do use **MediaPlayerElement** in UWP to play videos. However, occasionally (the occurance seems to be rare), the video which is working normally in any other way fails with following exception:

```
A valid type has not been set for this stream or a stream that it dependes on. (Exception from HRESULT 
0xC00D6D60)
```

What can cause this exception in our case? How to prevent it?

Edit - added snippet according to RoyLi comment:

This is how we create MediaPlaybackItem.

```
StorageFile manifest_file = await Storage.MovieManifestFile(mi.UserGUID, mi.OrderItemGUID);

amscr = await AdaptiveMediaSource.CreateFromStreamAsync(
  await manifest_file.OpenReadAsync(),
  new Uri(mi.MPDManifestUrl),
  "application/dash+xml"
);

MediaSource converted_amscr = MediaSource.CreateFromAdaptiveMediaSource(amscr.MediaSource);

MediaPlaybackItem ampi = new MediaPlaybackItem(converted_amscr);
```

The video source is MPEG-DASH stream protected with PlayReady. The issue was reproduced only on some devices and it happened not just for MPEG-DASH, but also for PIFF files.

After creating the MediaPlaybackItem, we simply use it as source for MediaPlayerElement.

```
 me.MediaPlayer.Source = ampi;
 me.MediaPlayer.Play();
```

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet about how you played the video?

Comment: Added short snippet according to your request @RoyLi-MSFT

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377721/setinputtype-returns-error-code-c00d6d60

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks, I've already seen that topic. However, that describes issue of Dolby Audio Encoder. In our case, we're playing video files through MediaPlayerElement. So the issue is not related to that link. I can understand the technical nature of the exception described. However, there's no obvious way to fix it in our case.

Comment: Are you using any media profile in your project? Another thing is that have you tried the official [CameraAdvancedCapture](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraAdvancedCapture) sample?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT No, I don't use that. Actually, this error happens to us when we do use MediaPlayerElement to play PlayReady DRM protected video files and very occasionally.

Comment: @panpernicek Since you are testing this via PlayReady content from a stream, could you please share this with me through a public link? When you see the error shown during playback, is the content able to play at all? Or the error happens immediately after setting the source? At last, could you please provide more detail about the differences between the devices that show this error and the devices that do not?